# How to properly initialize an object using a "with" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble properly initializing a python object using a `with` statement.  See below for my source code:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        ...

    def __exit__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        ...

test_class_outside_of_c_manager = TestClass()
test_class_outside_of_c_manager_type = type(test_class_outside_of_c_manager)

with TestClass() as test_class_inside_c_manager:
    test_class_inside_c_manager_type = type(test_class_inside_c_manager)
```

The type of `test_class_outside_of_c_manager_type` is `TestClass`, whereas that of `test_class_inside_c_manager_type` is `NoneType`.  Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Do you return it from __enter__? I think what is returned from __enter__() becomes what is bound to the as

Comment: Usually, `self` is returned from `__enter__` after you do your `__enter__` shenanigans

Comment: Thank you very much!  Returning ```self``` from ```__enter__``` resolved everything

Comment: I will upgrade to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is returned from `__enter__()` is bound to the `as` variable of a with statement.

You probably just need:

```
def __enter__(self):
    ...
    return self
```

Comment: Thank you so much!